# synchronize EntityManager with database

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I deleted a record from the database, and the entity manager still references that deleted record.

I have the following query:

```
List results = em.createNamedQuery("Customers.findNew")
 .setParameter("status", "n")
 .getResultList();
```

I am getting back results which include the deleted record. I've read the entity manager [caches the database](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html) for better performance. This is fine if only the application using the entity manager is accessing the database. But what happens when multiple systems will access the same database?

### I have tried:

```
  1. em.flush()  
  2. em.refresh()        
  3. em.clear()
```

right before I use entity manager to query the database, to try and force a re synchronization but none of them do. I am still getting the same record that isn't in the database anymore.

## UPDATE

The program I used to delete record, **Oracle SQL Developer**, didn't commit changes. So JPA was working fine, it was the program I was using to make changes to the database hadn't committed the changes. If you are experiencing similar problem make sure the db admin program committed changes.

Comment: evict everything from the L1 and L2 caches perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityManagers cache Objects themselves, for their own use. This is generally save.

In addition, you can enable the 2nd level cache, where inconsistencies can arise between systems. If you enabled this, try to disable it.

Did you delete the entity using the same EntityManager? If no, make sure the transaction to delete the entity is commited and make sure the transaction of your reading EntityManager starts after the deletion is commited.

Comment: I don't know TOAD, but how do transactions work there? I know a DB admin program where you have to commit explicitely.

Comment: you are correct my db program hadnt committed the changes.